# Is it possible to load an entire collection from a database in RavenDB using python/pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, ravendb, data-extraction

I am using document_store from pyravendb to use session to load an entity as a data frame. I would like to know if it is possible to load a collection and get it as a data frame?

```
from pyravendb.store import document_store
document_store = document_store.DocumentStore("http://live-test.ravendb.net", "DemoUser-08fef053-7143-4fc7-9860-bc415838799d")
document_store.initialize()
with document_store.open_session() as session:
    employee = session.load(["employees/8-A"])
    display(employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole collection by using a query,

For example "from Orders" query will return you all documents from Orders collection.

Examples:

- https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client#query
- https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client/blob/144a016ebb9395d215d5ce4274c5fb9ea8630b4d/pyravendb/tests/session_tests/test_query.py#L191